# How can I stop this horse from following me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

At some point in the past, I'd jumped on a horse that was tethered in a camp somewhere and rode it for a while before getting bored of it.

I didn't *steal* the horse - the name was in white when I jumped on - and now whenever I fast travel to an external location the horse appears next to me. It does, however, immediately start to wander off - presumably back towards the camp I found it at.

How do I get this horse to stop following me?
Preferably *without* killing it.

Comment: Overly attached horse.

Comment: Take the carrot out of your back pocket.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The system seems to think that you own the horse now.

Your options are:

- Buy your own horse, so that your own horse re-appears instead of that horse.
- Load the save file where the horse was not following you yet...
- Kill it! <sub>Bonus points from me if you do it with falling damage but manage to survive yourself, then it gets killed by accident... :)</sub>

Comment: Yeah, thought as much and I really can't find anything to indicate otherwise. Oh well. Have a tick :)

Comment: Oow oow, I have an idea: 1. Go to the top of the throat of the world and find a nice cliff. 2. Get off horse. 3. Unrelenting Force. 4. Evil laugh

Comment: @Coomie don't type Unrelenting Force in this type of instructions, type FUS RO DAH

Comment: +1 for: " Bonus points from me if you do it with falling damage but manage to survive yourself, then it gets killed by accident... :) ".

Answer (score 19):

Look, guys, I know how much we all love murder. But in the interests of animal welfare, let me suggest an alternative that does not involve hurting the poor thing.

If you want to get rid of an automatically following horse, whether it's your own or one the game just thinks is your own, you can simply get on a horse that isn't yours.

This does count as stealing, but if you get away they should forget about it. Getting on that horse will make it the active horse. Once you get off the horse, it will run back to its righteous owner, making it disowned, but the game won't recognise your old one as the active one until you get back on it.

Your "own" horse will return to the stables it originated from.

Comment: If you have Dawnguard, and you've completed the Soul Cairn Horse Quest, you can use the [Summon Arvak](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Summon_Arvak) spell to conjure up a demon horse which only lasts a minute. You can still ride it though and reset your "active" horse that way. :)

Answer (score 2):

Horses like to fight.  Pick a fight with a dragon and let the horse be the fodder.

Answer (score 0):

Summon Arvak the skeleton horse and your horse will return to its respawn spot.

Comment: You should add information like, **how** to summon them. The Help Center contains wonderful tips to answering a question very well. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the answers didn't work for me and Shadowmere, the horse from the brotherhood that I never asked for and don't want. So I just used the console... click the horse, type `disable` and hit enter. Problem solved.

It was very annoying that every time I try to sneak up on someone, the horse runs in and fights it instead. And it's probably reversible using `prid <refid>` and then `enable`.