# How can I get Shadowmere to stop following me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Not exactly the same as [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/how-can-i-stop-this-horse-following-me). **EDIT**: The solution to that question involves killing the horse. Shadowmere is immortal. This is not the same question.

I have gotten far enough in the Dark Brotherhood that I have been gifted with an immortal horse. The problem is, horses in this game seem more of a burden than a help, especially since Shadowmere seems intent on reporting any crimes he sees me commit.

Can I stable him somewhere so that he doesn't follow me around every time I fast travel? Is there any way to get rid of this annoying (and creepy) horse?

Comment: Your _Shadowmere_ reports crimes? Mine even commits them in its berserk-mode ...

Comment: You would think a horse gifted to you by the Dark Brotherhood wouldn't report your crimes.

Comment: I don't see how this isn't a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @Wipqozn Because I didn't steal this horse, and I *can't* kill this horse.

Comment: Since when does shadowmwere report crimes...its a horse. its also the best dragon slaying horse you can get in game i don't understand why you would want to get rid of it.

Comment: The chickens used to report crimes according to the developers, this never made release though. So it's not that big a leap that a horse might.

Comment: According to Reddit, mudcrabs still do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the Shadowmere present in Oblivion, Shadowmere in Skyrim is not marked as Essential and can die, killing Shadowmere works for making it stop following you temporarily.

However, 15-20 days later, Shadowmere will respawn in the location of death, causing it to start following you again

Shadowmere just seems invunerable, as it heals at the same rate as damage is applied. The only way to kill Shadowmere is to apply enough damage to it so it loses all of it's health in a single blow.

If your skills are high enough with a bow, you do not have to one shot Shadowmere. By sneaking and applying the 3.0x bonus and critical damage bonus you can use the Bound Bow or a Daedric Bow and use about 5 arrows to kill it. The same can be applied to all weapons or magic. Be sure to use weapons strong enough that Shadowmere's health regeneration can not keep up with.

Comment: While this is good information, it still doesn't answer the core question. I want Shadowmere to stop following me indefinitely. I don't want to have to go out of my way to kill it every 15-20 days.

Answer (score 7):

No, it is a bug. The horse dies for (but not for good) if you do that. She can also die if given a lot of damage at the same time. As from a dragon. She is not immortal, just heals herself fast. Jumping from very high cliffs kill her, because it is a lot of damage at the same time. You could also try to buy a new horse, ride on it, and then kill it. I have not tried yet, but if you own many horses the ones you are not using are stabled where you bought them. So maybe shadowmere would be stabled in the black pool next to the sanctuary.

*EDIT
This buying/riding and then killing it works. Shadowmere stays where you dismounted her. Also, if she gets killed, she will respawn at the spot where she died and wait in the same maner. So if she dies, mark it, and come back to the spot in a couple of weeks.

Comment: is this an answer or a comment? I'm not sure what the "No, it is a bug. The horse dies for good if you do that." refers to. If it's to another answer, it needs to be a comment.

Comment: Sorry, not too familiar with this board. Found it after some searching through google.

Comment: No problem SkyrimPlayer. Which answer did you want to comment on? I can turn it into a comment for you.

Answer (score 2):

This may work if the previous answers about killing Shadowmere don't work.

Open the console and select Shadowmere by clicking on him. Run the command:

```
disable
```

This will make the horse invisible, remove collision and disable the AI.

Comment: Does this count as "cheating"?

Comment: @JuanManuel No, he'd be fixing bugs (the crime reporting), not cheating. Unless, of course, the developers intended for Shadowmere to report crimes. Then he would be cheating. As for the Steam achievements, It's been reported that using the console doesn't disable them.

Comment: @Fambida: I think he means, will this prevent you from obtaining achievements?  The game can't tell the difference between when someone is trying to cheat and when someone is just fixing a ridiculous bug.

Comment: @JuanManuel Console commands do not count as cheating. Reference: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/37695/2923

Answer (score 2):

Kill Shadowmere at the top of throat of the world. She will stop following you and will wait for ever. At least she did when I killed her.

Answer (score 1):

You can kill Shadowmere. She will come back to life in 15-20, in the same spot she died, but will not follow you after that, unless you mount her again. You don't have to keep killing her every 20 days.

Answer (score 1):

Get Arvak if you have the Dawngaurd add-on, that will solve your problems. A horse you can conjure up when you need it is kind of a win.